# virtualized windows 7 from existing disk

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vmware-fusion

I have a laptop that is non functional that had windows vista installed on it. Is it possible to virtualize its harddrive onto my mac?

Comment: Windows 7 or Windows Vista? Do you have VMware Fusion already, as indicated by the tags? The answer to your question is *yes*, but what have you  tried already? You can probably use any imaging tool for your Windows hard drive and then boot that image through VMware.

Comment: i havent tried yet but will soon. just seeing if its possible.